# Validate avatar image

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I want to know if that code is correct and readable.

In class avatar the method *getAvatar()* validates the data. It checks if the field is not empty and if the photo extension is correct. If not, an appropriate exception is thrown. Class *AvatarUpdating* is responsible for updating the avatar in the database.

#### Avatar validation

```
declare(strict_types=1);

class Avatar
{
    public function __construct(
        private $data,
    ){}

    public function getAvatar(): string
    {
        $val = $this->data['avatar'];

        if(empty($val))
        {
            throw new ValidationException("Choose picture");
        }
        else if(!in_array($this->getExtension(), ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']))
        {
            throw new ValidationException("Incorrect extension");
        }
        return $val;

    }

    private function getExtension(): string
    {
        $val = $this->data['avatar'];

        return pathinfo($val, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    }
}

class ValidationException extends Exception {}
```

#### Avatar update

```
declare(strict_types=1);

class AvatarUpdating
{

    public function  __construct(
        private $database,
    ){}

    public function UpdateAvatar(int $id, string $photo): void
    {
            $query = $this->database->ConnectDatabase()->prepare("UPDATE user set avatar = :avatar where user_id = :id");
            $query->bindParam(':avatar', $photo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();
    }
}
```

#### view

```
$avatarValidation = new Avatar($_POST);
$update_avatar = new AvatarUpdating($database);

div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileLang" lang="pl-Pl" name="avatar">
                    <label class="custom-file-label border border-dark" for="customFileLang">Wybierz awatar</label>
                    <span class="error">
                        <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['submit_avatar']))
                        {
                            try {
                                    $update_avatar->UpdateAvatar($_SESSION['user_id'], $avatarValidation->getAvatar());
                                }catch (ValidationException $exception)
                                {
                                    echo $errorMessage = $exception->getMessage();
                                }
                        }
                        ?>
            </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mb-3" name="submit_avatar">Dodaj</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is the code readable to get the first job?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: The new title was better than the original, so I've put it back.

Comment: Did you test your code? Does it produce the correct output?

Comment: Can you update the question to include how the "view" is invoked? Because it's not really a view and a lot should be changed here. But hard to recommend anything without more context.

Comment: Is there a layer in between the view and the classes? There are some fundamental issues here, but you only seem to care about readability.

Answer (score 1):

## Make unique exception sub-classes

It is good that `ValidationException` is declared as a subclass of `Exception` so that individual type of exception can be caught instead of all exceptions, though it would be better to make separate unique sub-classes - e.g. `EmptyAvatarException` and `InvalidExtensionException`. That way the error message can exist in the front-end coded and the back-end code won't have to deliver the message. One advantage of this is that the front-end could display messages in different languages if necessary.

## Follow PHP Standards Recommendations for readability

While there is no de-facto rules about readability conventions and it is up to individuals/teams to decide their conventions, idiomatic PHP code often follows the [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) - e.g. [PSR-12: Extended Coding Style](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/). The code presented follows many of the recommendations though not all. For the complete list see [this analysis result](https://www.phptools.online/php-checker/result/7fa21169-2d60-43ad-98dd-6713a598a1ad). The first thing I had noticed before doing the analysis was spacing after keywords like `if`:

> ```
> if(empty($val))
> ```

Idiomatic PHP code has a space after the `if`:

```
if (empty($val))
```

And opening braces for conditional blocks don't need to go on a separate line - that is only for functions, methods and class definitions:

```
if (empty($val)) {
```